# WiredTiger causes problems when starting MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, debian

Let's start with my logs that I get when executing **`mongod`** in my terminal console on my Linux Server:
https://pastebin.com/QwKW1QHi

I can't really describe the problem because I don't know exactly what it is but it I think it has something to do with WiredTiger. I googled a lot about this error(s) and tried out many "solutions" but they haven't worked.

What I've tried so far:

- Created the /data/db folder
- Give MongoDB all permissions on the /data/db folder
- Restarted MongoDB many times

I appreciate any help!

Comment: lets start with why do you think you have a problem?  Looking at the logs, it looks like wiretiger recovered from the journal.  Did you do a hard shutdown then restart while doing write operations?

Comment: Normally when I typed in mongod, the mongod console opened and I could enter mongod commands. Now it just shows logs. And yes I had a hard shutdown after I‘ve noticied that mongodb doesn‘t run like before @barrypicker

Comment: the mongod does not have a console available for user interaction - it is the database engine.  When you start the mongod it may output some log information and then enter a wait state waiting for connections.  The mongo shell is a command line utility for interacting with the mongod process.  To use the mongo shell assuming you have your mongod running on localhost with default port of 27107 simply type `mongo`  (notice no 'd' in the command)